# How to merge some values of related JSON files in one JSON array

Tags: php, json

I am learning php and want to combine certain key values of 3 related json files into one. My goal is to print all of the bookings with some additional values from the sites and trucks files.

1. bookings - https://www.bnefoodtrucks.com.au/api/1/bookings
2. sites - https://www.bnefoodtrucks.com.au/api/1/sites
3. trucks - https://www.bnefoodtrucks.com.au/api/1/trucks

The first file contains values in the following format

```
**Bookings**
{
title: "London Spuds - Sun 27 Jun",
truck_id: "11741",
site_id: "525",
start: "2021-06-27T17:00:00+10:00",
finish: "2021-06-27T20:00:00+10:00"
},
```

I want to use the site_id value from this file to obtain only the ‘latitude’ and ‘longitude’ values from a different JSON file, in the following format

```
**sites**
{
site_id: 525,
title: "River Terrace",
description: "With a panoramic view of the city, River Terrace is a popular recreational space for both residents and visitors. The park is well utilised throughout the week, from morning to evening.Serving times:Monday - Sunday5.00pm to 8.00pm ",
street: "3A River Terrace",
suburb: "Kangaroo Point",
state: "QLD",
postcode: 4169,
country: "Australia",
latitude: -27.476447,
longitude: 153.035316,
spots: 2,
cost: "1 tokens",
image: 
{
src: "https://www.bnefoodtrucks.com.au/sites/foodtrucks/files/styles/header/public/images/sites/river_tce.jpg?itok=67PaqEnk",
alt: "",
title: ""
},
map: 
{
src: "https://www.bnefoodtrucks.com.au/sites/foodtrucks/files/images/sites/river_tce_0.jpg",
alt: "",
title: ""
}
},
```

I also want to use the truck_id value from the first JSON file to obtain the ‘website’ value from a third JSON file, which has the following format

```
**sites**
{
truck_id: "11741",
name: "London Spuds",
category: "",
bio: "London Spuds is a family owned Foodie adventure! We specialise in creating the most delicious Fresh, Hot Baked Potatoes! Our spuds are cooked to perfection in our Traditional English Potato Ovens - then filled to the brim with only the best quality meats and freshest ingredients. Our amazing meals are completely gluten free, and are the perfect comfort food. All food is prepared & cooked in a Brisbane City Council approved 5 star mobile food truck kitchen. Our customers LOVE them and our talented team LOVE to give you great food at a stellar price. Guaranteed to make you Happy! We can't wait to have you try our fabulous SPUDS!",
avatar: 
{
src: "https://www.bnefoodtrucks.com.au/sites/foodtrucks/files/styles/avatarlarge/public/images/bcc_admin/londonspuds_foodtruck_profile.jpg?itok=huZ6vUZE",
alt: "",
title: ""
},
cover_photo: 
{
src: "https://www.bnefoodtrucks.com.au/sites/foodtrucks/files/styles/header/public/images/London%20Spuds/img_9926.jpg?itok=dhLarTid",
alt: "",
title: ""
},
website: "https://www.londonspuds.com.au/",
facebook_url: "https://www.facebook.com/londonspuds/",
instagram_handle: "londonspuds",
twitter_handle: ""
},
```

Desired output:

```
{
title: "London Spuds - Sun 27 Jun",
truck_id: "11741",
site_id: "525",
start: "2021-06-27T17:00:00+10:00",
finish: "2021-06-27T20:00:00+10:00"
latitude: -27.476447,
longitude: 153.035316,
website: "https://www.londonspuds.com.au/",
},
```

I have been able to merge bookings and site information using the code below but it is not what I desire as I only need to add the latitude and longitude values.

```
<?php
$array1 = file_get_contents("https://www.bnefoodtrucks.com.au/api/1/bookings");
$array2 = file_get_contents("https://www.bnefoodtrucks.com.au/api/1/sites");

$decode_one = json_decode($array1,TRUE);
$decode_two = json_decode($array2,TRUE);

function merge_json_decoded_arrays($decode_one,$decode_two) {
    $data = array();
    $arrayAB = array_merge($decode_one,$decode_two);
    foreach ($arrayAB as $value) {
      $id = $value['site_id'];
      if (!isset($data[$id])) {
        $data[$id] = array();
      }
      $data[$id] = array_merge($data[$id],$value);
    }
    return $data;
  }
  $merged_array = merge_json_decoded_arrays($decode_one,$decode_two);
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($merged_array);
  echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Any guidance much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key idea here is to organize the sites and trucks data in such a way that we can easily associate them with the bookings. We're going to do that by creating associative arrays (maps) for the sites and trucks, using the site_id and truck_id as the key, respectively.

We can then loop through the bookings and easily pull the related site and truck records to extract the fields we need from them, and insert them into the booking record.

```php
/**
 * Enrich booking entries with data from the sites and trucks
 *
 * @param $bookings - Data from the Bookings API endpoint
 * @param $sites - Data from the Sites endpoint
 * @param $trucks - Data from the Trucks endpoint
 * @return array
 */
function enrichBookings($bookings, $sites, $trucks)
{
    /*
     * Create a map (associative array) for the site data,
     * using the site_id as the key
     */
    $siteMap = [];
    foreach ($sites as $currSite)
    {
        $siteMap[$currSite['site_id']] = $currSite;
    }

    /*
     * Create a map (associative array) for the truck data,
     * using the truck_id as the key
     */
    $truckMap = [];
    foreach ($trucks as $currTruck)
    {
        $truckMap[$currTruck['truck_id']] = $currTruck;
    }

    // Create a buffer for the output
    $output = [];

    /*
     * Loop through the bookings records, adding fields from
     * the sites and trucks data
     */
    foreach ($bookings as $currBooking)
    {
        // If we don't have a site record matching the ID, skip this booking and echo an error
        if (!array_key_exists($currBooking['site_id'], $siteMap))
        {
            echo 'No site found for booking ' . json_encode($currBooking) . PHP_EOL;
            continue;
        }

        // If we don't have a truck record matching the ID, skip this booking and echo an error
        if (!array_key_exists($currBooking['truck_id'], $truckMap))
        {
            echo 'No truck found for booking ' . json_encode($currBooking) . PHP_EOL;
            continue;
        }

        // Create variables for the current site and truck records to make them easy to refer to
        $currSite  = $siteMap[$currBooking['site_id']];
        $currTruck = $truckMap[$currBooking['truck_id']];

        // Add the lat ang lng from the site to the booking
        $currBooking['latitude']  = $currSite['latitude'];
        $currBooking['longitude'] = $currSite['longitude'];

        // Add the website from the truck to the booking record
        $currBooking['website'] = $currTruck['website'];

        // Add the enriched booking to the output buffer
        $output[] = $currBooking;
    }

    // Return the enhanced records
    return $output;
}

$bookingsJson = file_get_contents("https://www.bnefoodtrucks.com.au/api/1/bookings");
$sitesJson    = file_get_contents("https://www.bnefoodtrucks.com.au/api/1/sites");
$trucksJson   = file_get_contents("https://www.bnefoodtrucks.com.au/api/1/trucks");

try
{
    // Decode all of the JSON strings, throw excaptions so that we know when there is a problem with the input
    $bookingsDecoded = json_decode($bookingsJson, true, 512, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);
    $sitesDecoded    = json_decode($sitesJson, true, 512, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);
    $trucksDecoded   = json_decode($trucksJson, true, 512, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);

    // Call our function to enrich the bookings with data from the other endpoints
    $output = enrichBookings($bookingsDecoded, $sitesDecoded, $trucksDecoded);

    // How's it look, pretty cunning, don't you think?
    echo json_encode($output, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) . PHP_EOL;
}
catch (JsonException $e)
{
    // json_decode chucked a wobbly, let's see why...
    echo $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```json
[
    {
        "title": "Skewer Me - Fri 25 Jun",
        "truck_id": "29111",
        "site_id": "2",
        "start": "2021-06-25T11:30:00+10:00",
        "finish": "2021-06-25T14:30:00+10:00",
        "latitude": -27.46791667,
        "longitude": 153.0235556,
        "website": "http:\/\/www.skewerme.com.au"
    },
    {
        "title": "Andy's Kangaroo and Currywurst - Thu 24 Jun",
        "truck_id": "29921",
        "site_id": "2",
        "start": "2021-06-24T11:30:00+10:00",
        "finish": "2021-06-24T14:30:00+10:00",
        "latitude": -27.46791667,
        "longitude": 153.0235556,
        "website": ""
    },
    {
        "title": "London Spuds - Sun 27 Jun",
        "truck_id": "11741",
        "site_id": "525",
        "start": "2021-06-27T17:00:00+10:00",
        "finish": "2021-06-27T20:00:00+10:00",
        "latitude": -27.476447,
        "longitude": 153.035316,
        "website": "https:\/\/www.londonspuds.com.au\/"
    },
    {
        "title": "London Spuds - Thu 1 Jul",
        "truck_id": "11741",
        "site_id": "2",
        "start": "2021-07-01T11:30:00+10:00",
        "finish": "2021-07-01T14:30:00+10:00",
        "latitude": -27.46791667,
        "longitude": 153.0235556,
        "website": "https:\/\/www.londonspuds.com.au\/"
    },
    {
        "title": "Andy's Kangaroo and Currywurst - Thu 1 Jul",
        "truck_id": "29921",
        "site_id": "2",
        "start": "2021-07-01T11:30:00+10:00",
        "finish": "2021-07-01T14:30:00+10:00",
        "latitude": -27.46791667,
        "longitude": 153.0235556,
        "website": ""
    },
    {
        "title": "Skewer Me - Thu 1 Jul",
        "truck_id": "29111",
        "site_id": "525",
        "start": "2021-07-01T17:00:00+10:00",
        "finish": "2021-07-01T20:00:00+10:00",
        "latitude": -27.476447,
        "longitude": 153.035316,
        "website": "http:\/\/www.skewerme.com.au"
    },
    {
        "title": "Skewer Me - Fri 2 Jul",
        "truck_id": "29111",
        "site_id": "2",
        "start": "2021-07-02T11:30:00+10:00",
        "finish": "2021-07-02T14:30:00+10:00",
        "latitude": -27.46791667,
        "longitude": 153.0235556,
        "website": "http:\/\/www.skewerme.com.au"
    },
    {
        "title": "Skewer Me - Thu 24 Jun",
        "truck_id": "29111",
        "site_id": "525",
        "start": "2021-06-24T17:00:00+10:00",
        "finish": "2021-06-24T20:00:00+10:00",
        "latitude": -27.476447,
        "longitude": 153.035316,
        "website": "http:\/\/www.skewerme.com.au"
    },
    {
        "title": "Skewer Me - Thu 8 Jul",
        "truck_id": "29111",
        "site_id": "525",
        "start": "2021-07-08T17:00:00+10:00",
        "finish": "2021-07-08T20:00:00+10:00",
        "latitude": -27.476447,
        "longitude": 153.035316,
        "website": "http:\/\/www.skewerme.com.au"
    },
    {
        "title": "London Spuds - Thu 8 Jul",
        "truck_id": "11741",
        "site_id": "2",
        "start": "2021-07-08T11:30:00+10:00",
        "finish": "2021-07-08T14:30:00+10:00",
        "latitude": -27.46791667,
        "longitude": 153.0235556,
        "website": "https:\/\/www.londonspuds.com.au\/"
    },
    {
        "title": "The Tasty Pocket - Thu 1 Jul",
        "truck_id": "19311",
        "site_id": "395",
        "start": "2021-07-01T11:30:00+10:00",
        "finish": "2021-07-01T16:00:00+10:00",
        "latitude": -27.47366667,
        "longitude": 153.0292778,
        "website": ""
    },
    {
        "title": "Eat The Thing - Fri 2 Jul",
        "truck_id": "22601",
        "site_id": "525",
        "start": "2021-07-02T17:00:00+10:00",
        "finish": "2021-07-02T20:00:00+10:00",
        "latitude": -27.476447,
        "longitude": 153.035316,
        "website": "https:\/\/www.eatthething.com.au"
    },
    {
        "title": "Lankan Streetz - Fri 25 Jun",
        "truck_id": "31611",
        "site_id": "2",
        "start": "2021-06-25T11:30:00+10:00",
        "finish": "2021-06-25T14:30:00+10:00",
        "latitude": -27.46791667,
        "longitude": 153.0235556,
        "website": "https:\/\/www.lankanstreetz.com.au"
    },
    {
        "title": "Andy's Kangaroo and Currywurst - Thu 8 Jul",
        "truck_id": "29921",
        "site_id": "2",
        "start": "2021-07-08T11:30:00+10:00",
        "finish": "2021-07-08T14:30:00+10:00",
        "latitude": -27.46791667,
        "longitude": 153.0235556,
        "website": ""
    },
    {
        "title": "Skewer Me - Fri 16 Jul",
        "truck_id": "29111",
        "site_id": "2",
        "start": "2021-07-16T11:30:00+10:00",
        "finish": "2021-07-16T14:30:00+10:00",
        "latitude": -27.46791667,
        "longitude": 153.0235556,
        "website": "http:\/\/www.skewerme.com.au"
    },
    {
        "title": "Skewer Me - Thu 15 Jul",
        "truck_id": "29111",
        "site_id": "525",
        "start": "2021-07-15T17:00:00+10:00",
        "finish": "2021-07-15T20:00:00+10:00",
        "latitude": -27.476447,
        "longitude": 153.035316,
        "website": "http:\/\/www.skewerme.com.au"
    },
    {
        "title": "Skewer Me - Fri 9 Jul",
        "truck_id": "29111",
        "site_id": "2",
        "start": "2021-07-09T11:30:00+10:00",
        "finish": "2021-07-09T14:30:00+10:00",
        "latitude": -27.46791667,
        "longitude": 153.0235556,
        "website": "http:\/\/www.skewerme.com.au"
    },
    {
        "title": "Gelato \u00e0 Go-Go - Thu 24 Jun",
        "truck_id": "12611",
        "site_id": "395",
        "start": "2021-06-24T11:30:00+10:00",
        "finish": "2021-06-24T16:00:00+10:00",
        "latitude": -27.47366667,
        "longitude": 153.0292778,
        "website": "http:\/\/www.gelatoagogo.com.au"
    },
    {
        "title": "Gelato \u00e0 Go-Go - Fri 25 Jun",
        "truck_id": "12611",
        "site_id": "395",
        "start": "2021-06-25T11:30:00+10:00",
        "finish": "2021-06-25T16:00:00+10:00",
        "latitude": -27.47366667,
        "longitude": 153.0292778,
        "website": "http:\/\/www.gelatoagogo.com.au"
    },
    {
        "title": "Gelato \u00e0 Go-Go - Wed 30 Jun",
        "truck_id": "12611",
        "site_id": "395",
        "start": "2021-06-30T11:30:00+10:00",
        "finish": "2021-06-30T16:00:00+10:00",
        "latitude": -27.47366667,
        "longitude": 153.0292778,
        "website": "http:\/\/www.gelatoagogo.com.au"
    },
    {
        "title": "Gelato \u00e0 Go-Go - Fri 2 Jul",
        "truck_id": "12611",
        "site_id": "395",
        "start": "2021-07-02T11:30:00+10:00",
        "finish": "2021-07-02T16:00:00+10:00",
        "latitude": -27.47366667,
        "longitude": 153.0292778,
        "website": "http:\/\/www.gelatoagogo.com.au"
    },
    {
        "title": "Gelato \u00e0 Go-Go - Wed 7 Jul",
        "truck_id": "12611",
        "site_id": "395",
        "start": "2021-07-07T11:30:00+10:00",
        "finish": "2021-07-07T16:00:00+10:00",
        "latitude": -27.47366667,
        "longitude": 153.0292778,
        "website": "http:\/\/www.gelatoagogo.com.au"
    },
    {
        "title": "Gelato \u00e0 Go-Go - Thu 8 Jul",
        "truck_id": "12611",
        "site_id": "395",
        "start": "2021-07-08T11:30:00+10:00",
        "finish": "2021-07-08T16:00:00+10:00",
        "latitude": -27.47366667,
        "longitude": 153.0292778,
        "website": "http:\/\/www.gelatoagogo.com.au"
    },
    {
        "title": "Gelato \u00e0 Go-Go - Fri 9 Jul",
        "truck_id": "12611",
        "site_id": "395",
        "start": "2021-07-09T11:30:00+10:00",
        "finish": "2021-07-09T16:00:00+10:00",
        "latitude": -27.47366667,
        "longitude": 153.0292778,
        "website": "http:\/\/www.gelatoagogo.com.au"
    },
    {
        "title": "Gelato \u00e0 Go-Go - Wed 14 Jul",
        "truck_id": "12611",
        "site_id": "395",
        "start": "2021-07-14T11:30:00+10:00",
        "finish": "2021-07-14T16:00:00+10:00",
        "latitude": -27.47366667,
        "longitude": 153.0292778,
        "website": "http:\/\/www.gelatoagogo.com.au"
    },
    {
        "title": "Gelato \u00e0 Go-Go - Thu 15 Jul",
        "truck_id": "12611",
        "site_id": "395",
        "start": "2021-07-15T11:30:00+10:00",
        "finish": "2021-07-15T16:00:00+10:00",
        "latitude": -27.47366667,
        "longitude": 153.0292778,
        "website": "http:\/\/www.gelatoagogo.com.au"
    },
    {
        "title": "Gelato \u00e0 Go-Go - Fri 16 Jul",
        "truck_id": "12611",
        "site_id": "395",
        "start": "2021-07-16T11:30:00+10:00",
        "finish": "2021-07-16T16:00:00+10:00",
        "latitude": -27.47366667,
        "longitude": 153.0292778,
        "website": "http:\/\/www.gelatoagogo.com.au"
    },
    {
        "title": "Gelato \u00e0 Go-Go - Sat 10 Jul",
        "truck_id": "12611",
        "site_id": "395",
        "start": "2021-07-10T11:30:00+10:00",
        "finish": "2021-07-10T16:00:00+10:00",
        "latitude": -27.47366667,
        "longitude": 153.0292778,
        "website": "http:\/\/www.gelatoagogo.com.au"
    },
    {
        "title": "Gelato \u00e0 Go-Go - Tue 29 Jun",
        "truck_id": "12611",
        "site_id": "395",
        "start": "2021-06-29T11:30:00+10:00",
        "finish": "2021-06-29T16:00:00+10:00",
        "latitude": -27.47366667,
        "longitude": 153.0292778,
        "website": "http:\/\/www.gelatoagogo.com.au"
    },
    {
        "title": "Gelato \u00e0 Go-Go - Mon 28 Jun",
        "truck_id": "12611",
        "site_id": "395",
        "start": "2021-06-28T11:30:00+10:00",
        "finish": "2021-06-28T16:00:00+10:00",
        "latitude": -27.47366667,
        "longitude": 153.0292778,
        "website": "http:\/\/www.gelatoagogo.com.au"
    },
    {
        "title": "Gelato \u00e0 Go-Go - Mon 5 Jul",
        "truck_id": "12611",
        "site_id": "395",
        "start": "2021-07-05T11:30:00+10:00",
        "finish": "2021-07-05T16:00:00+10:00",
        "latitude": -27.47366667,
        "longitude": 153.0292778,
        "website": "http:\/\/www.gelatoagogo.com.au"
    },
    {
        "title": "Gelato \u00e0 Go-Go - Tue 6 Jul",
        "truck_id": "12611",
        "site_id": "395",
        "start": "2021-07-06T11:30:00+10:00",
        "finish": "2021-07-06T16:00:00+10:00",
        "latitude": -27.47366667,
        "longitude": 153.0292778,
        "website": "http:\/\/www.gelatoagogo.com.au"
    },
    {
        "title": "That Gelato Truck - Sat 17 Jul",
        "truck_id": "36121",
        "site_id": "395",
        "start": "2021-07-17T11:30:00+10:00",
        "finish": "2021-07-17T16:00:00+10:00",
        "latitude": -27.47366667,
        "longitude": 153.0292778,
        "website": ""
    },
    {
        "title": "That Gelato Truck - Thu 1 Jul",
        "truck_id": "36121",
        "site_id": "395",
        "start": "2021-07-01T11:30:00+10:00",
        "finish": "2021-07-01T16:00:00+10:00",
        "latitude": -27.47366667,
        "longitude": 153.0292778,
        "website": ""
    },
    {
        "title": "Numero Uno - Sat 26 Jun",
        "truck_id": "32921",
        "site_id": "525",
        "start": "2021-06-26T17:00:00+10:00",
        "finish": "2021-06-26T20:00:00+10:00",
        "latitude": -27.476447,
        "longitude": 153.035316,
        "website": ""
    }
]
```

There is a lot of opportunity for enhancement, we could spin off into space coming up with clever ways to make this configurable, object-oriented, etc, but this is a good, solid approach that is easy to understand.

Comment: Thankyou this works perfectly and is easy to understand

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest the following solution:

```
class Unifier
{
    private $jsonFiles = [
        "bookings" => "https://www.bnefoodtrucks.com.au/api/1/bookings",
        "sites"    => "https://www.bnefoodtrucks.com.au/api/1/sites",
        "trucks"   => "https://www.bnefoodtrucks.com.au/api/1/trucks"
    ];

    private $jsons;

    private $json;

    private $joins;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function getJson()
    {
        $this->applyJoins();
        return $this->json;
    }

    /**
     * Unifier constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        foreach($this->jsonFiles as $jsonFileName => $jsonFileUrl) {
            $this->jsons[$jsonFileName] = json_decode(file_get_contents($jsonFileUrl), true);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return bool|void
     * @throws Exception
     */
    private function applyJoins()
    {
        if (is_null($this->joins)) {
            return true;
        }

        foreach ($this->joins as $joinedJsonName => $join)
        {
            if (!isset($join['join_key'])) {
                throw new Exception('Missing expression joinBy().');
            }

            foreach ($this->json as $key => $element)
            {
                try
                {
                    $filter = array_filter($this->jsons[$joinedJsonName], function($k) use ($join, $element) {
                        return $k[$join['join_key']] == $element[$join['join_key']];
                    });

                    $this->json[$key] = array_merge($element, array_values($filter)[0]);
                }
                catch (Exception $exception) {
                    continue;
                }
            }

            unset($this->joins[$joinedJsonName]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param $name
     * @return Unifier
     */
    public function json($name)
    {
        $this->json = $this->jsons[$name];
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param $json
     * @return Unifier
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function join($json)
    {
        if (is_callable($json)) {
            $json($this);
            return $this;
        }

        if (!isset($this->jsonFiles[$json])) {
            throw new Exception('Json file with name "' . $json . '" not present in Unifier::jsonFiles.');
        }

        $this->joins[$json] = [];
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param $key
     * @return Unifier
     */
    public function joinBy($key)
    {
        $this->joins[array_key_last($this->joins)]['join_key'] = $key;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param $keys
     * @return mixed
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function select($keys): array
    {
        if (is_string($keys)) {
            $keys = (array)$keys;
        }

        $json = $this->getJson();
        foreach ($json as $key => $element) {
            $intersectKeys = array_intersect_key($element, array_flip($keys));
            if (!empty($intersectKeys)) {
                $json[$key] = $intersectKeys;
            }  else {
                unset($json[$key]);
            }
        }

        return array_values($json);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$json = (new Unifier)->json('bookings');

// Join sites to json by site_id.
$json->join('sites')->joinBy('site_id');

// Join trucks to json by truck_id.
$json->join('trucks')->joinBy('truck_id');

// Select desired output.
$output = $json->select([
    'title', 
    'truck_id', 
    'site_id', 
    'start', 
    'finish', 
    'latitude', 
    'longitude', 
    'website'
]);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($output);
echo '</pre>';
```

The same, but in a shorter form:

```
$output = (new Unifier)->json('bookings')->join(function($json) {
    $json->join('sites')->joinBy('site_id')->join('trucks')->joinBy('truck_id');
})->select([
    'title', 'truck_id', 'site_id', 'start', 'finish', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'website'
]);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($output);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: That's pretty slick.